# How to draw polygons using Abaqus python script

Tags: python, 2d, polygon, surface, abaqus

I have (X,Y) coordinates of polygons as shown in the picture [pores image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMNMd.png). How can I import them to Abaqus and how to create a surface in a way that subtract the internal shapes (polygon1,poly2....) from the external shape (the frame (a rectangle)). Rectangle-poly1-poly2....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try recording a macro. Manually create the model using Abaqus CAE. I assumed you're doing a 2-D model, so your geometry will probably be:

1. A solid rectangle.
   2a. Planar cut on the rectangle created through a sketch.
   2b. Alternatively, you can use the "create wire" feature to input your shape coordinates (right-click to read coordinates from a text file). Use merge scheme "Separate wire". Then, use the "Partition" tool to partition the holes, and then use "Geometry Edit" to remove the undesired faces.

Anyways, the macro recorder will help prototype the code that you will need to generate. Once you do that, you're going to need to do typical Python file open/read operations to read the input coordinates and develop the program to generate the model and mesh. Or, you can extruciatingly generate your model manually using the method I outlined above. There's a lot of ways to skin this chicken.